# Ошибка при парсинге Json с Retrofit 2

Tags: android, json, retrofit

```
ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<AdvertListResponse> call = apiInterface.getAdvertList();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<AdvertListResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<AdvertListResponse> call, Response<AdvertListResponse> response) {
            Log.i("ssss",""+response.body());
            AdvertListResponse listResponse = response.body();
            DataAdvertList dataAdvertList = listResponse.getDataAdvertLists().get(0);
            List<InfoAdvertList> advertList = dataAdvertList.getInfoAdvertLists();
            Log.i("ssss","advert"+advertList);
            boolean succes = dataAdvertList.isSuccess();
            if(succes){
                Log.i("ssss",""+succes);
                Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                realm.beginTransaction();
                realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(advertList);
                realm.commitTransaction();
            }else {
                String error = dataAdvertList.getErrors().get(0);
                Toast.makeText(AdvertActivity.this,"error"+error,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<AdvertListResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.i("ssss",t.toString());
            Toast.makeText(AdvertActivity.this,t.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

public class AdvertListResponse {
@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private List<DataAdvertList> dataAdvertLists = new ArrayList<DataAdvertList>();

public List<DataAdvertList> getDataAdvertLists() {
    return dataAdvertLists;
}

public void setDataAdvertLists(List<DataAdvertList> dataAdvertLists) {
    this.dataAdvertLists = dataAdvertLists;
}
```

}

```
public class DataAdvertList {

@SerializedName("success")
@Expose
private boolean success;
@SerializedName("object")
@Expose
private List<InfoAdvertList> infoAdvertLists;
@SerializedName("errors")
@Expose
private List<String> errors;

public boolean isSuccess() {
    return success;
}

public void setSuccess(boolean success) {
    this.success = success;
}

public List<InfoAdvertList> getInfoAdvertLists() {
    return infoAdvertLists;
}

public void setInfoAdvertLists(List<InfoAdvertList> infoAdvertLists) {
    this.infoAdvertLists = infoAdvertLists;
}

public List<String> getErrors() {
    return errors;
}

public void setErrors(List<String> errors) {
    this.errors = errors;
}
```

}

```
public class InfoAdvertList extends RealmObject{
@PrimaryKey
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private String id;
@SerializedName("cat_id")
@Expose
private String catId;
@SerializedName("is_dogovornaja")
@Expose
private String isDogovornaja;
@SerializedName("is_obmen")
@Expose
private String isObmen;
@SerializedName("description")
@Expose
private String description;
@SerializedName("email")
@Expose
private String email;
@SerializedName("city_id")
@Expose
private String cityId;
@SerializedName("address")
@Expose
private String address;
@SerializedName("phone1")
@Expose
private String phone1;
@SerializedName("phone2")
@Expose
private String phone2;
@SerializedName("phone3")
@Expose
private String phone3;
@SerializedName("phone4")
@Expose
private String phone4;
@SerializedName("phone5")
@Expose
private String phone5;
@SerializedName("coords")
@Expose
private String coords;
@SerializedName("is_new")
@Expose
private String isNew;
@SerializedName("mark_id")
@Expose
private String markId;
@SerializedName("model_id")
@Expose
private String modelId;
@SerializedName("user_id")
@Expose
private String userId;
@SerializedName("price")
@Expose
private String price;
@SerializedName("created")
@Expose
private String created;
@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private String status;
@SerializedName("is_favourite")
@Expose
private Integer isFavourite;
@SerializedName("modelname")
@Expose
private String modelname;
@SerializedName("markname")
@Expose
private String markname;
@SerializedName("photos")
@Expose
private RealmList<PhotoAdvert> photos;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getCatId() {
    return catId;
}

public void setCatId(String catId) {
    this.catId = catId;
}

public String getIsDogovornaja() {
    return isDogovornaja;
}

public void setIsDogovornaja(String isDogovornaja) {
    this.isDogovornaja = isDogovornaja;
}

public String getIsObmen() {
    return isObmen;
}

public void setIsObmen(String isObmen) {
    this.isObmen = isObmen;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getCityId() {
    return cityId;
}

public void setCityId(String cityId) {
    this.cityId = cityId;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getPhone1() {
    return phone1;
}

public void setPhone1(String phone1) {
    this.phone1 = phone1;
}

public String getPhone2() {
    return phone2;
}

public void setPhone2(String phone2) {
    this.phone2 = phone2;
}

public String getPhone3() {
    return phone3;
}

public void setPhone3(String phone3) {
    this.phone3 = phone3;
}

public String getPhone4() {
    return phone4;
}

public void setPhone4(String phone4) {
    this.phone4 = phone4;
}

public String getPhone5() {
    return phone5;
}

public void setPhone5(String phone5) {
    this.phone5 = phone5;
}

public String getCoords() {
    return coords;
}

public void setCoords(String coords) {
    this.coords = coords;
}

public String getIsNew() {
    return isNew;
}

public void setIsNew(String isNew) {
    this.isNew = isNew;
}

public String getMarkId() {
    return markId;
}

public void setMarkId(String markId) {
    this.markId = markId;
}

public String getModelId() {
    return modelId;
}

public void setModelId(String modelId) {
    this.modelId = modelId;
}

public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(String price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public String getCreated() {
    return created;
}

public void setCreated(String created) {
    this.created = created;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public Integer getIsFavourite() {
    return isFavourite;
}

public void setIsFavourite(Integer isFavourite) {
    this.isFavourite = isFavourite;
}

public RealmList<PhotoAdvert> getPhotos() {
    return photos;
}

public void setPhotos(RealmList<PhotoAdvert> photos) {
    this.photos = photos;
}

public String getModelname() {
    return modelname;
}

public void setModelname(String modelname) {
    this.modelname = modelname;
}

public String getMarkname() {
    return markname;
}

public void setMarkname(String markname) {
    this.markname = markname;
}
```

}

Вот такая ошибка выходить
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 38 path $.data[0].object[0]

Вот json ответ

```
{"data":[{"success":true,"object":[{"id":"2","cat_id":"1","is_dogovornaja":"1","is_obmen":"1","description":"\u043e\u043f\u0438\u0441\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435 \u0442\u043e\u0432\u0430\u0440\u0430","email":"test@gmail.com","city_id":"1","address":"\u0433. \u0410\u043b\u043c\u0430\u0442\u044b, \u0443\u043b. \u0428\u0430\u0448\u043a\u0438\u043d\u0430 54","phone1":"(777)123-4567","phone2":"(777)423-3567","phone3":"(777)523-2567","phone4":"(777)323-1567","phone5":"(777)723-0567","coords":"44.2536545, 46.525656332","is_new":"1","mark_id":"1","model_id":"1","user_id":"54","price":"100000","created":"1481446357","status":"1","is_favourite":0,"modelname":"Samsung Galaxy S7","markname":"Samsung","photos":[{"id":"1","url":".\/uploads\/ob\/3ece2520bd8a1f36a16983ffc52d8ad8_0.jpg"},{"id":"2","url":".\/uploads\/ob\/3ece2520bd8a1f36a16983ffc52d8ad8_1.jpg"}]}],"errors":[]}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас data это один объект DataAdvertList, вы пытаетесь добыть массив.

Вместо

```
public List<DataAdvertList> getDataAdvertLists() {
    return dataAdvertLists;
}
```

и

```
@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private List<DataAdvertList> dataAdvertLists = new ArrayList<DataAdvertList>();
```

и

```
DataAdvertList dataAdvertList = listResponse.getDataAdvertLists().get(0);
```

Напишите так:

```
public DataAdvertList getDataAdvertLists() {
    return dataAdvertLists;
}
```

и

```
@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private DataAdvertList dataAdvertLists;
```

и

```
DataAdvertList dataAdvertList = listResponse.getDataAdvertLists();
```

Comment: Но у меня ошибка не в date, а object в классе InfoAdvertList.Если поменять как вы сказали то выходит ошибка в date Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 10 path $.data